# PayPal recurring payments using codeigniter PayPal_Lib library

Tags: php, codeigniter, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-subscriptions

how to integrate recurring payments using codeigniter PayPal_Lib library ?

Answer (score 2):

http://tareqalam.wordpress.com/2010/07/07/paypal-recurring-payment-integrated-with-codeigniter/